# full width image pushed off page

Tags: graphics

Hi Im trying to insert an image fullwidth spanning both columns. At the moment the image is just pushed to the side and runs off the page. What can I do to recenter the image and force the position of the image in the document?
[image]

Comment: Welcome! You can try `\begin{figure*}\centering\includegraphics{<file>}\end{figure*}`. If that does not help, please post the code that produced this output.

Comment: Hi And thank you so much for your suggestion. Are you able to view the image provided?

Comment: No one on this site wants to type in text from a screen shot to be able to play with a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overleaf indicates a lot of errors in your screenshot, e.g. you have to end `\begin{figure*}` with `\end{figure*}`. However, the `*` should not be neccessary to scale a graphic in a two column document to the appropriate size.

You can use `width=\columnwidth` instead of `width=\textwidth`. I tried to reproduce your example and `columnwidth` worked for me. This must have something to do with how your twocolumn document is set up.

```
\begin{figure}[tbh]
\vspace{0.1cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{SingleCompElem.png}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:alrc}
    \footnotesize
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{figure}
```

Some other tips:

- Provide your code in text form in future questions, so users here can easily copy and test it.
- You can insert `\,` between numbers and units or use the `siuntix` package, e.g. `250\,khz` or, after adding `\usepackage{siunitx}` to your preamble, `\SI{25}{\kilo\hertz}`, which will both insert a small space between the number and unit that makes it look better and avoid linebreaks between number and unit.

Comment: Wow -yes thank you SOOOOOO much ive been looking at this for two days now! Thank you ever so much.